# Sylvester matrix and GCD degree

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, polynomials, matrix-equations

How to prove that the degree of a $\gcd$ of two polynomials is equal to the dimension of the null space of the Sylvester matrix?

I know that any linear combination of the rows of $S(u,v)$ is a linear combination of the two polynomials, but I don't know how to get the result.
Please any help .

Answer (score 1):

The idea of the answer is given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_matrix#Applications) in the wikipedia entry on the [Sylvester matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_matrix) of two polynomials. In short: [Bézout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity#B.C3.A9zout.27s_identity_for_polynomials). But it takes a few more details than those displayed on wikipedia to be convinced. I think...

Let $p, q$ be degree $m,n$ polynomials over a field $F$. And let $S_{p,q}\in M_{m+n}(F)$ denote their Sylvester matrix.

As you already observed, we can see the transpose $S_{p,q}^T$ as a linear map from $F_{n-1}[X]\times F_{m-1}[X]$ to $F_{m+n-1}[X]$. It suffices to identify $F^k$ with with $F_{k-1}[X]$, the vector space of all polynomials of degree not greater than $k-1$ over $F$, via canonical bases. In particular, this yields 
$$
S_{p,q}^T(x,y)=0\iff px+qy=0
$$
Since $\dim \ker S_{p,q}=\dim \ker S_{p,q}^T$, your question amounts to: how does one prove that

> $$
> \dim \ker S_{p,q}^T=\deg \gcd(p,q)
> $$

Let $g$ be the gcd of $p$ and $q$, and write $p=gp_0$, $q=gq_0$ with $\gcd(p_0,q_0)=1$. Now observe that for a given pair $(x,y)\in F_{n-1}[X]\times F_{m-1}[X]$
$$
px+qy=0\iff p_0x=-q_0y \iff x=q_0z \;\mbox{and}\; y=-p_0z\quad 
$$
for some unique $z\in F_{d-1}[X]$ where $d$ is the degree of $\gcd(p,q)$.
Therefore we have an isomorphism
$$
F_{d-1}[X]\simeq \ker S_{p,q}^T\quad\mbox{given by}\quad z\longmapsto (q_0z,-p_0z)
$$
The result follows. By rank-nullity, this can also be stated as

> $$
> \deg \gcd (p,q)=\deg p+\deg q -\mathrm{rank} S_{p,q}
> $$